# How to reach the buttom of the page using Selenium::Remote::Driver in perl?

Tags: perl, selenium

I am writing a test script for website where a button appears as the user reach end of the  page and list of various option.

So I am trying to reach the bottom of the page of the website.

```
     my $driver= Selenium::Remote::Driver->new;
     $driver->get('http://www.test.com');
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

achieved the objective using javascript

```
     my $script = q{window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);};
     my $elem = $driver->execute_script($script);
```